# How to return nth value from one Column based on another Column using ArrayFormula or QUERY?

Tags: google-sheets, filter, count, vlookup, google-query-language

I'm working with a long, growing list of ratings data, and I'm trying to find a way to reference the 2nd (3rd, 4th, etc.) rating.

[Here's a link to the sheet I'm working on.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kr2iSSirmlq9vumaQKqX2ZVa29CXkVqL1dfnK2K0C4o/edit?usp=sharing)

The data I want to reference is in `F5:H`. I'm using `QUERY` to show most of the info I want (see `A5` in my sheet for this formula), but where I'm running into trouble is when I try to retrieve *only* the Nth rating from `Column H` for a particular client based on the Client in `Column A`.

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious... the biggest (potential) limitation is that I need a formula that I can put in `D5` that auto-fills this info for the entire column.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A5:A="",, IFNA(VLOOKUP(A5:A, 
 FILTER(G5:H, COUNTIFS(G5:G, G5:G, ROW(G5:G), "<="&ROW(G5:G))=2), 2, ), 
 VLOOKUP(A5:A, G5:H, 2, ))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @player0 !!! That works perfectly. I hadn't even considered using `FILTER` inside the `ARRAYFORMULA`, but I guess it works here because `ARRAYFORMULA` is referencing the `VLOOKUP` and not `FILTER` directly? Either way, the important thing is that it works... thank you again!

Comment: @confuseddesk yes, AF is there for IF and VLOOKUP